# In python, how to manage importing and using different class functionality?

Tags: python, django, class, oop, object

I have three python classes, 'x', 'A' and 'B' in separate modules x.py,a.py and b.py
Here I am using class x's method in class A and class B

```
class x:
    def display(self):
        print ("Hello python")

class A:             # case 1
    from . import x  # class level import
    x_object = x()   # class level object
    def my_method(self):
        x_object.display()

class B:             #case 2
    def my_method(self):
        from . import x  # method level import
        x_object = x()   # method level object
        x_object.display()
```

So,in above scenarios I used class level import and object creation and method level import and object creation, my questions are as-

- which is best approach considering performance?
- how memory utilization work for both scenario?
- In above scenario, if I am using "my_method()" very frequently from django view. There will be 10000 concurrent requests accessing view from which method "my_method" is being called?
- is there any best way to use different class functionality in django view which give max performance and best memory management

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can remove `from . import x` from `A`'s definition and it still behaves the same.

Comment: @wwii Sorry, I forgot to mention classes belongs from separate modules .

Comment: What is the reason for using classes at all here? Do either of these classes keep any state?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman yes

Answer (score 0):

this link, suggests all the best practice of importing
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports